# How to Label Encode a Large Data

Tags: python, pandas

I have [data](https://deepctr-doc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_images/movielens_sample.png) with a size of 5 GB for [a machine learning task](https://deepctr-doc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Examples.html#regression-movielens). I have to label encode it, but the data can't be read once at all.

Reading with `chunksize` to a pandas data frame doesn't make sense, because the encoder must see the whole column at once to encode properly.

How can I deal with this size of data?

Comment: Did you try it with Google colab? - https://colab.research.google.com/

Comment: @JimTodd do you think It's able to just load the entire data and process it?

Comment: Yes, it will be able to process the data. You can store the data in Google drive(it can store15GB data), and access it via google colab. The inbuilt reasonably free GPU will handle the data faster as much as it can.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's working well with Google Colab.